# Android: EditText with Progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-edittext

I'm building a browser, and I have an address bar (as EditText) on top of the WebView. What I would like to do is to present the loading of the page graphically in the background of the EditText, much like in the iphone's browser. Is this possible?

Thanks

---

UPDATE

So far I have tried the ClipDrawable approach. What I did was to take the stock drawable android.R.drawable.editbox_background and create 2 versions - a white background and a blue one (to show the progress). Then I would create a LayerDrawable like so:

```
 barDrawable = addressBar.getBackground();

    Drawable progress = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.editbox_progress);
    cbarDrawable = new ClipDrawable(progress, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    cbarDrawable.setLevel(0);

    layerlist = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { barDrawable, cbarDrawable });

    addressBar.setBackgroundDrawable(layerlist);
```

and then I would call setLevel as the loading progresses. The problem now is that there are weird issues such as: the white drawable is too big or it moves to the top.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this link](http://colintmiller.com/2010/10/07/how-to-add-text-over-a-progress-bar-on-android/), which talks about overriding ProgressBar's onDraw() method and drawing text over it. That should get you started at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do it by using 2 images/shapes set as the EditText's background Drawable and changing their width programmatically

Comment: It's definetly possible that is the how the galaxy tab browser works. I think Damp is on the right path. The tricky part is going to be making it still display the normal EditText frame. Perhaps you can edit drawable to make everything but the frame transparent then put a progress bar underneath it.

Comment: @Alex1987 an example would require quite a bit of time for me to do, but there's tons of resources out there on how to change background drawables / making compound drawables, etc... Note however that as @Tim said it will be hard to keep the frame and I'm pretty sure you won't be able to use EditText's native frame.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a [ClipDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) as the background for the text.